# Retrieving data from multiple-page API using Talend

Tags: api, loops, pagination, talend

I have an API with 59 pages, on each page 1000 rows of data. I would like to retrieve all that data and store it in a Microsoft SQL Server.

When I use tloop with a condition run until i<59, it returns the first 1000 rows of data 59 times which is clearly not what I need.

I have tried to create a global variable next_page but I do not know how to connect it to the `next_page` present in the API, so that when "next_page"="" the program will know to break the loop.

Comment: Can you provide the actual code that you have written so far.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar case (difference is that I didn't have a "nextPage" element but a "nextLink" which was giving me the complete URL to get to the nextPage).

1. I created a globalvariable "endJob" with value "false" at the beginning (tJava right before tLoop)
2. My tLoop is from int i=1, iteration is i++ , condition is !endJob (thus it will loop as long as the job is not marked as ended).
3. In a tJava right after tLoop, create the URL for your API request, using your page number, which is the tLoop_1_CURRENT_ITERATION
4. Then after my tRestClient, I put a tReplicate : first flow is for your needed transformations, the other one retrieve only the "nextPage" item. If nextPage is empty, then you update "endJob" variable to "true" : you want to stop the loop.

[image]